# Issue with instance.loginRedirect() Not Redirecting

Tags: typescript, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, react-typescript

I'm setting up Azure Single Sign-On (Azure AD SSO) in a React application, and I'm encountering an issue when using **instance.loginRedirect()**.

Here's the problem:

When I use **instance.loginPopup()**, the authentication process works fine. After a successful login, it redirects me to the /profile page as expected.

However, when I use **instance.loginRedirect()**, the behavior is not as expected. After a successful login, I'm redirected to the SignIn page instead of the /profile page.

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'; // Import Navigate from react-router-dom
import { MsalProvider, AuthenticatedTemplate, useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import SignInRoute from './components/SignInRoute';
import ProfileRoute from './components/Profile';

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'client_id',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { accounts } = useMsal();
  const isAuthenticated = accounts.length > 0;

  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/SignIn" element={<SignInRoute />} />
            {/* Add a Route to redirect from / to /SignIn */}
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/SignIn" />} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfileRoute />} />

          </Routes>
          <AuthenticatedTemplate>
            {isAuthenticated && (
              <button onClick={() => msalInstance.logout()}>Sign Out</button>
            )}
          </AuthenticatedTemplate>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </MsalProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

SignIn.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import '../css/SignIn.css';

import logo from '../images/logo.png';

const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const { accounts } = useMsal();

  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      await instance.loginPopup();
      // Redirect to the profile page upon successful sign-in
      window.location.href = '/profile';
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error signing in:', error);
    }
  };

  // If the user is already authenticated, redirect to the profile page
  if (accounts.length > 0) {
    window.location.href = '/profile';
  }

  return (
    <div className="signin-container">
      <div className="logo-and-text">
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo" />
        <h2 className="signin-text">Sign In</h2>
      </div>
      <button className="signin-button" onClick={handleSignIn}>
        Sign In with Azure AD
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

SingInRoute.tsx

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const SignIn = lazy(() => import('./SignIn'));

const SignInRoute: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <SignIn />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default SignInRoute;
```

I want to understand why **instance.loginRedirect()** is not redirecting me to the /profile page after a successful login and what could be the potential reasons for this behavior. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `instance.loginPopup()`, it is an asynchronous operation, and you have control over what happens after the login is successful (i.e., the manual redirect to the `/profile` page using `window.location.href = '/profile'`).

On the other hand, `instance.loginRedirect()` is meant for redirect-based authentication, where the page is redirected to the identity provider for authentication and then back to your application. In this case, the redirect to the `/profile` page should be handled by the library after a successful authentication.

- Make sure that the redirect to `/profile` is not happening before the authentication process is completed. In your `handleSignIn` function, try removing the manual redirect and let the library handle it.

```
const handleSignIn = async () => {
  try {
    await instance.loginPopup();
    // No manual redirect here
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error signing in:', error);
  }
};
```

- Handle errors in the redirect flow. You can use the `handleRedirectCallback` method from MSAL to handle the redirect callback and check for errors.

```
useEffect(() => { instance.handleRedirectCallback().then(() => {
 // Check for errors and redirect to the appropriate page  
 if (instance.getAccount()) {
  window.location.href = '/profile'; } }); 
  }, 
[instance]);
```

- Ensure that the `/profile` route is properly configured and accessible

`<Route path="/profile" element={<ProfileRoute />} />`

**Result**
[image]

[image]
[image]